# ASP.Net, control clientID in ddl OnClientSelectedIndexChanged target?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `runat='server'` dropdown in ascx control.

I want to fire a javascript function named with the control ID.

```
function ToggleClasses_<%= Me.ID %>(){...
```

I'm doing it this way because it answers a lot of problems and greatly decreases the amount of code to maintain since this control is on the page several times. I don't like it but it seems to be the most simple and direct answer to what I'm doing.

I have in the ddl code the following:

```
...OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="ToggleClasses_<%= Me.ID %>();"...
```

In the javascript block, the function is properly named like you would expect.

However, in the ddl event code, it is rendered to HTML like this:

```
onChange="ToggleClasses_&lt;%= Me.ID %>();"
```

I've tried a few things I've found here on SO but those are all about putting the client id in the parameter list, not the function name/call and so doesn't help me out (they don't work for what I'm doing anyway).

How ought I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to add the event on the server side code, not the ASPX file.

For example (in VB):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ddl.OnClientSelectedIndexChanged = "ToggleClasses_" + Me.ID + "();"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use '<' in the client event like OnClientSelectedIndexChanged. This will get HTML encoded before rendering to browser.

Please use the following code to make it work;

```
OnClientSelectedIndexChanged = "ToggleClasses_" + Me.ClientID + "();";
```

ClientID will generate the rendered ID.